# Fill input depending on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these radio buttons:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td><input id="rooom" name="room" type="radio" value="single"><strong>Single Room: 85 euros</strong></td>
      <td width="30"></td>
      <td><input id="rooom" name="room" type="radio" value="double"><strong>Double Room: 95 euros</strong></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to the value to appear in this input:

```
(...)
<td><label>Cost of Accomodation =</label></td>
<td width="5"></td>
<td><input id="cost" class="input_reg_cost" name="cost" type="text"></td>
(...)
```

This is my script but it isn't working, I don't know if it is abotu he the syntax or an error mine.

```
$("#rooom").change(function() {
    var sel = $(this).val();
    if (sel=='single') {
    $("#cost").val('85')
    }
    if (sel=='double') {
    $("#cost").val('95')        
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the syntax:

```
$(".rooom").change(function () {
    var sel = $(this).val();
    if (sel == 'single') {
        $("#cost").val('85');
    }
    if (sel == 'double') {
        $("#cost").val('95');
    }
});
```

Remember to always close jQuery functions with });

rooom is also a class, not an id, so you'll want to replace that # with a .

Comment: Semicolon on JS is optional.

Comment: Oops, removed.  Thanks for the heads-up!